# ignore part of directory in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, ignore

I need to ignore a directory but keep tracking of one subfolder of this directory. My files tree looks like:

```
root
 -d1
  --bin
  --bin/data
 -d2
  --bin
  --bin/data
```

I need to ignore the bin directory but keeping tracking of the bin/data dir in all the folders of my repo. Rigth now I'm using:

```
syntax: glob
*/obj/*
*/bin/*
*.swp
```

but when I run hg status, can't see if there is something new in my data dirs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this will do what you need.

```
syntax: glob
*/obj/*
*.swp

syntax: regexp
/bin/(?!data)
```